# How to obtain an exact infinite-precision representation of rational numbers via a non-standard FlatZinc extension?

Tags: minizinc, flatzinc, mzn2fzn

By default `mzn2fzn` automatically computes the result of a floating point division within a *MiniZinc* model, and stores it as a constant *float* value in the resulting *FlatZinc* model.

**Example:**

The file `test.mzn`

```
var float: x;
constraint      1.0 / 1000000000000000000000000000000000.0 <= x;
constraint x <= 2.0 / 1000000000000000000000000000000000.0;
solve satisfy;
```

translated with

```
mzn2fzn test.mzn
```

becomes equal to

```
var 1e-33..2e-33: x;
solve satisfy;
```

---

What we would like to obtain***, instead, is a *FlatZinc* file along the following lines:

```
var float: x;
var float: lb;
var float: ub;
constraint float_div(1.0, 1000000000000000000000000000000000.0, lb);
constraint float_div(2.0, 1000000000000000000000000000000000.0, ub);
solve satisfy;
```

where `float_div()` is a *newly* introduced, non-standard, *FlatZinc* constraint.

Is it possible to generate such an encoding of the original problem by using a variant of the `std` directory of constraints, or does this encoding require a more significant change of the source code of the `mzn2fzn` tool? In the latter case, could we have some guidance?

---

***: we have some formulas for which the finite-precision floating-point representation is unsuitable, because it changes a `SAT` result into `UNSAT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no way of generating FlatZinc with infinite precision. Although the idea has been discussed a few times, it would require much of MiniZinc to be rewritten or appended using a library that could provide these infinite precise types. Libraries like these, such as the Boost `interval` library, seem to be lacking in options and do currently not compile for all machine targets on which MiniZinc is distributed. There seem to be various interesting cases for infinite precise types, but within the implementation of the MiniZinc compiler we are still looking for finding a decent way of implementing them.

Although infinite precision is not on the table. The MiniZinc compiler does intend to be correct according to the floating point standards. Feel free to report any problems that might occur to the [MiniZinc Issue Tracker](https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues).

Comment: So the answer is no, even if we don't need any solving support but just a translation support? The flatzinc model with infinite precision may easily be handled by optimathsat, our only problem is how to preserve those values through the mzn2fzn translation. I don't think it's a bug of minizinc, some intervals of numbers simply cannot be represented with floats and that's why the solution of the problem changes.

Comment: There is indeed no way of doing this at this time as all non-integers are represented internally as floating point numbers. So even when not being integrated into the domain of a variable, the constraints would still be subject to floating point rounding

Comment: I see. I imagine the same limitation would apply if the arguments were integers in the minizinc file, we would still only be able to use up to 64 bits. Thank you for the answer.